# How to allow the charset= utf-8 to be accepted by ASP.Net WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

***It seems the charset-utf-8 is causing the timeout. I remove that and the post goes through.  So, I guess the question is how to allow the utf-8 to be accepted by webapi***

I'm having a hard time putting my finger on what is blocking (causing timeouts) from POSTs to my WebAPI service.  I have nothing special (code below) and have just default configuration. It seems that if the header

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

comes in, then the calling service times out.  If the header is not there, it works.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
```

Comment: Hi Peter! Interesting Question. From some quick Googling I can see that the default MediaTypeFromatter for WebApi should be able to handle UTF-8. Is this perhaps a browser issue? I've seen some discrepancies in the way different browsers handle content types. Wish I could help more.

Comment: HI Paul, it's server to server.  SendGrid has a event notification service that is pushing out results to my ORCSWeb windows server.  SendGrid tells me exactly what headers they push out and I can duplicate the error by pushing those headers.  when I remove the utf8, it works correctly.

Comment: anyone else with ideas?